# Proving that a specific linear functional exists.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $I=[0,1]$ with $L^\infty=L^\infty(m)$, how might I go about showing that there is a bounded linear functional $\Lambda\neq0$ on $L^\infty$ that is $0$ on $C(I)$? (This then shows that there is no $g\in L^1(m)$ that satisfies $\Lambda f=\int_I f\cdot g\space dm$ for every $f\in L^\infty$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $L := \overline{C(I)}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}$ is a closed (proper) subspace of $L^{\infty}$. Pick $f_0 \in L^{\infty} \backslash L$, $f_0 \neq 0$, and define $$\tilde{\Lambda}(f) := \lambda$$ for $f := \ell+\lambda f_0$, $\ell \in L$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that this defines a bounded linear functional on the linear space $\text{lin}(L \cup \{f_0\})$. Apply the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$C(I)$ is a closed proper subspace of $L^\infty(I)$. Choose $p \in L^\infty(I) \setminus C(I)$ and use Hahn Banach to find a bounded linear functional $\phi$ that separates $C(I)$ and the compact set $\{p\}$. In particular, we have $\phi(x) < \phi(p)$ for all $x \in C(I)$. It follows from homogeneity that $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in C(I)$.